# Form Select element with multipart/form-data enctype

Tags: ajax, forms, select, multipartform-data, enctype

I'm using select element with multiple selections and image field for my `Ajax` form. For submitting image, I've to use form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. When I submit the form, the post data for my multiple select element named "business_type" is as follow since I select three options from select element.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="business_type"    
Manufacturer
-----------------------------212041485118126
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="business_type"   
Wholesaler
-----------------------------212041485118126
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="business_type"    
Trading House
```

Now, in my $_REQUEST array (In PHP), I'm receiving only the last item as it is obvious from above-mentioned post data. How can I get the other selected values?

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple trick that worked for me is by replacing the select element name `name="business_type"` with an array as follow.

Replace

```
<select name="business_type" multiple required>
```

with

```
<select name="business_type[]" multiple required>
```

So getting the array of all selected fields in post data.